# Socket - Can you put it another thread?

Tags: c#, sockets

Bit stuck on this I am...

Scenario:

A socket handling game emulator to send and receive coded data encoded in VL64 and other strings. Needs to support about 4000 socket requests etc.

At the moment it uses the AsyncCallback to perform Async server roles etc.

Code:

```
private static SnowTcpListener mServer;

mServer = new SnowTcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, "IP"), backlog, new OnNewConnectionCallback(SessionManager.HandleIncomingConnection));
```

Backlog is a int for the Socket backlog.

SnowTcpListener

```
/// <summary>
    /// Callback to be invoked upon accepting a new connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Socket">Incoming socket connection</param>
    public delegate void OnNewConnectionCallback(Socket Socket);

    /// <summary>
    /// Reality simple asynchronous TCP listener.
    /// </summary>
    public class SnowTcpListener : IDisposable // Snow prefix to avoid conflicts with System.Net.TcpListener
    {
        private Socket mSocket;
        private OnNewConnectionCallback mCallback;

        public SnowTcpListener(IPEndPoint LocalEndpoint, int Backlog, OnNewConnectionCallback Callback)
        {
            mCallback = Callback;

            mSocket = new Socket(LocalEndpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            mSocket.Bind(LocalEndpoint);
            mSocket.Listen(Backlog);

            BeginAccept();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (mSocket != null)
            {
                mSocket.Dispose();
                mSocket = null;
            }
        }

        private void BeginAccept()
        {
            try
            {
                mSocket.BeginAccept(OnAccept, mSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult Result)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket ResultSocket = (Socket)mSocket.EndAccept(Result);
                mCallback.Invoke(ResultSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            BeginAccept();
        }
```

SessionManager.HandleIncomingConnection:

```
public static void HandleIncomingConnection(Socket IncomingSocket)
        {
            bool Reject = ModerationBanManager.IsRemoteAddressBlacklisted(IncomingSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0]);

            Output.WriteLine((Reject ? "Rejected" : "Accepted") + " incoming connection from " + IncomingSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + ".",
                OutputLevel.Informational);

            if (Reject)
            {
                try
                {
                    IncomingSocket.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception) { }

                return;
            }

            lock (mSyncRoot)
            {
                uint Id = mCounter++;
                mSessions.Add(Id, new Session(Id, IncomingSocket));
            }
        }
```

And then it creates a new "Session"

```
public Session(uint Id, Socket Socket)
{
    mId = Id;
    mSocket = Socket;
    mBuffer = new byte[512];
    mPongOk = true;

    mSocket.SendBufferSize = 512;

    BeginReceive();
}
```

Which inturn calls BeginRecieve()

```
private void BeginReceive()
        {
            try
            {
                if (mSocket != null)
                {
                    //TODO: BeginRecieve();
                    mSocket.BeginReceive(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveData), mSocket);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                SessionManager.StopSession(mId);
            }
        }
```

OnRecieveData()

```
private void OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult Result)
        {
            int ByteCount = 0;

            try
            {
                if (mSocket != null)
                {
                    ByteCount = mSocket.EndReceive(Result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            if (ByteCount < 1 || ByteCount >= mBuffer.Length)
            {
                SessionManager.StopSession(mId);
                return;
            }

            ProcessData(ByteUtil.ChompBytes(mBuffer, 0, ByteCount));
            BeginReceive();
        }
```

If you need anymore code, just ask.

How would i go about creating it so the connections were in a separate thread, or how would I improve my socket experience, as were getting to a certain amount of sessions and it is just lagging up. I have tried to increase the buffer, but it made it worse.

I have come to the end of my tether now, I have tried nearly everything I can think of and I could really do with some help!

Thanks for reading this very long post, and If the question is not clear, ill try and make it clearer for you!

Cheers
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you done to assess the bottlenecks and performance problems in your existing code?  Have you profiled it using any tools?

From the code posted this far, you just keep asynchronously receiving new connections (BeginAccept) and incoming data (BeginReceive). None of which should cause any degrading performance. But the BeginReceive function calls "ProcessData" which is presumably where all your business logic is for handling messages.  I suspect that is where your bottleneck is at.  But that's just a guess.

You said 4000 sockets, so a "thread per connection" doesn't sound like the right design.

But since you are already doing asynchronous sockets, then right approach seems to be to call ProcessData in a work pool thread.  And when ProcessData completes, just call BeginReceive again on that session object.  Something like the following:

```
private void OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult Result)
{
    int ByteCount = 0;
    try
    {
        if (mSocket != null)
        {
            ByteCount = mSocket.EndReceive(Result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }

    if (ByteCount < 1 || ByteCount >= mBuffer.Length)
    {
        SessionManager.StopSession(mId);
        return;
    }

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessDataInThread, ByteCount);

}

void ProcessDataInThread(object context)
{
    int ByteCount = (int)context;

    ProcessData(ByteUtil.ChompBytes(mBuffer, 0, ByteCount));
    BeginReceive();
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant and it worked excellently!